# Declaring a new list/set/dict in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, dictionary, set

I was wondering if there was any difference (performance, speed, ...) between these two notations:
 `new_list = []`  and  `new_list = list()`
?

Or is it a developer/team preference or even a recommendation in the language?
What about sets and dictionaries?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are some differences like:

```
list(('x','y'))
#['x', 'y']

[('x','y')]
#[('x', 'y')]

list(set('x'))
#['x']

[set('x')]
#[{'x'}]
```

`list()` is a function call while `[]` is a literal.

Also, there is a module called dis [dis doc](https://docs.python.org/3.10/library/dis.html):

*The dis module supports the analysis of CPython bytecode by disassembling it. The CPython bytecode which this module takes as an input is defined in the file Include/opcode.h and used by the compiler and the interpreter.*

To display the disassembly of `lambda: list()` and `lambda: []` see below:

```
import dis
print(dis.dis(lambda: list()))
#output
 1           0 LOAD_GLOBAL              0 (list)
              2 CALL_FUNCTION            0
              4 RETURN_VALUE

print(dis.dis(lambda: []))
#output
1           0 BUILD_LIST               0
              2 RETURN_VALUE
```

*Also, list is a global name that can be overridden during runtime so it is **highly discouraged to use `list` as your variable name**.
Coz you do not want to override in-built `list`.*